# How to convert first of year date type to varchar with concatenated text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select for my first column text + the first day of the current year. Because it is inserting into `varchar` column.

```
SELECT 
    'Balance as of' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0), 120, 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first day of the year, use `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1)
```

You can then convert this to any format you want:

```
SELECT 'Balance as of' + CONVERT(varchar(255), datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1), 120)
```

Of course, I would be happy with:

```
SELECT 'Balance as of' + DATENAME(year, GETDATE()) + '-01-01')
```

because I prefer the format YYYY-MM-DD.